# Haskell why using @ (as)

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

Came across this example:

```
buildEntry ws@(w:_) = (w, length ws)
```

What's the advantage of using `ws@(w:_)` instead of:

```
buildEntry' (w:ws) = (w, length (w:ws))
```

Since I am only a beginner, I think readability of the second example is also better.

Comment: From Richard Bird's Thinking Functionally with Haskell: 
 `Rather than deconstructing
a list and then reconstructing it again (a cheap but not free operation), it is better
to reuse the value that we matched with`

Comment: Would ghc really reconstruct the entire list here? Seems like a trivial rewrite rule

Comment: I think it's mainly for readability. And simple laziness of not wanting to type lots more characters. I agree the gain is minimal and perhaps debatable in this case, but what if you were deconstructing a more complex data structure.

Comment: For a Haskell challange at Hackerrank I wrote a function where I had to make a distinction between an empty list and a non-empty list. So I wrote `[]` for the first part of the function and `(x : xs)` for the second part. Elegent in my opinion because this gives you two disjoint cases. However my solution didn't passed, because of time-out or memory overflow, I do not know. So I replaced `(x : xs)` by `xs` and now it passed all the tests and I officially solved the problem. Stil do not understand why.

Comment: Being honest: it is a micro-optimization of exactly the kind Knuth warned us all against. And yet it is a habit that we all -- including me -- are in. It produces a bizarre feeling, trying to hold these two facts in my head at the same time.

Comment: I disagree about it being a micro-optimization. They both have to do the work of pattern matching on the list; the big difference is in which parts of the list get names. You can't make the mistake (silly though it might be) of building an incorrect argument like `w:w:ws` for `length`, because the work of "building" that argument is already done on the left where you can only *deconstruct* a list, not build a new one.

Comment: @chepner agree. code should be clear and direct as to what it is it manipulates. rebuilding the same value obfuscates this, and yes is error prone. more likely error though would be calling `length ws`, I think.

Comment: So no consensus here? I see a lot of great Haskell minds here with various opinions. More concrete question: if I were to stick to `buildEntry' (w:ws) = (w, length (w:ws))`, would this be in any way negative?

Comment: @Madderote: The only difference *in theory* is that `ws@(w:_)`…`length ws` calls `length` with the pointer to the *original* `(:)` constructor of which `w` is the first field, whereas `(w:ws)`…`length (w:ws)` calls `length` on a *new* `(:)` constructor with the pointers `w` and `ws` copied into its fields. But *in practice* I would expect GHC to notice that you’re reusing a value that’s identical to the pattern (and has the same type) and produce the same code in either case; and even if it weren’t optimised, the performance difference should be negligible (just copying a few words of memory).

Comment: @Jon Purdy: thanks for adding that. I did not consider that yet. I guess that if it will not jeopardise performance, I can conclude I'd stick with readability in which I favour  `(w:ws)` as a pattern.

Answer (score 5):

Readability is not always improved by removing the as-pattern. Compare

```
foo x@(C a b (D c d) (E e f)) = bar x
```

with

```
foo (C a b (D c d) (E e f)) = bar (C a b (D c d) (E e f))
```

I think the first one is more readable.

Further, there might be some performance differences. As far as I know, using `x@(C ...)` and then referring to `x` later will make GHC to define `x` as a pointer to the same memory cell holding `(C ...)`. Instead, using `(C ...)` with the same arguments can allocate a new "object" which is a copy of the original one.

Of course, GHC might apply a sort of CSE (common subexpression elimination) to keep only a copy around. However, since CSE is not always beneficial w.r.t. performance, GHC is quite conservative on using CSE.

Right now, I cannot see any issues in doing that optimization in this specific case, so maybe GHC could use CSE after all. Still, I'm unsure about this.

Comment: The first one could also be written `foo x@(C _ _ (D _ _) (E _ _)) = bar x`, letting you focus on the constructors involved, since the pattern match doesn't care about their arguments.

Comment: But this is just for exemplification.  I have numerous cases where I _do_use some or all of the arguments and also need to pass on the full structure in a call.

Comment: Another important distinction is that the second version is rife with the possibility of introducing errors. The first version says that we are passing `x` in its entirety into `bar`; the second version says that we are passing something that looks like `x` into `bar` but it might differ in some ways.